# Large XML Parsing Efficiently

Tags: c#, xml, performance, parsing, xml-parsing

I need to parse large XML Files and save data to MS SQL DB Tables. One way obviously to write C# Program. Obviously this raise a question of performance. Do you know any fastest and efficient way to process large scale XML?

Comment: Did you already consider using SSIS to handle this instead of build your own tool?

Comment: How large is large?  C# is going to be pretty fast at parsing XML.

Comment: Yes Thanks. SSIS is one option. But for complex transforms like in this case, SSIS packages that need to run in parallel and/or need to use a lot of memory. Any other thoughts in Mind ?

Comment: @ J E Carter II - XML Size 500 MB or sometimes more than that.

Comment: @ Henk - Okay. Thanks. That sounds promising! Any other Tools/Thoughts in mind ? Any XML Parsing Champ in the Room ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pursue a C# solution, look into `XmlReader`.  This will give you **forward only** streaming access to your XML file.  Note the forward only part.  If you need to do more complex manipulations for child nodes, you'd probably do well to use a combination of `XmlReader` and `XDocument`, i.e. loading the large file with an `XmlReader` and then using `ReadSubtree()` to load subtrees into XDocuments.  For example, if your document is something like:

```
<root>
    <big-child-1>
        <grandchild-a>
            ...
        </grandchild-a>
        <grandchild-b>
            ...
        </grandchild-b>
    </big-child-1>
    <big-child-2>
        ... 
    </big-child-2>
</root>
```

You might do something like this:

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("C:\\file.xml");\
xr.MoveToContent();

while (xr.Read())
{
    if (xr.Name == "grandchild-a")
    {
        XDocument xd = new XDocument(xr.ReadSubTree()); // now you have an XDocument with all the content under the grandchild-a node
    }
    else if (xr.Name == ...)
}
```

However, the more you can **just** use `XmlReader`, the more performant it'll be.

Here's some documentation:

- XmlReader: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- XDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You do have other options of course:

- SQL Server has XML functionality (look into `OPENXML`)
- SSIS: you mention concerns about memory usage here, but it's an option.
- XSLT: probably not as good an option as using `XmlReader` in this case, but you might be able to create XSLT that would then create a SQL query from your XML.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the details of your scenario.  How large is the XML file?  Are you storing the entire XML file in the database, or just certain parts of it?  Are you storing the XML as a blob in the database, or are you putting the different elements and attributes into their own dedicated columns?

C# will work fine for your needs, but there are different XML related APIs depending on your scenario.

If you want to deserialize the entire XML document into .NET objects, then you can define your objects in C# and use **System.Xml.Serialization.XMLSerializer** to load the document into memory.

However, if the document is really large, and you can't afford to load the whole thing into memory all at once, then probably you'll want to use **System.Xml.XmlReader**, which is a forward-only reader that you can use to grab elements and attributes one at a time, and shove them into your database.

Comment: Rajeev, Thanks. Here are few answers of your question. 1. Are we storing the entire XML file in the database, or just certain parts of it in our case? - Probably whole file, but not necessarily. 2. Are we storing the XML as a blob in the database, or are we putting the difference elements and attributes into their own dedicated columns? - definitely not as a blob. Different nodes to different Tables/Columns. 3. what is the Max size of XML ? Close to 500 MB.

Comment: Okay, then I would suggest System.Xml.XmlReader.  At 500MB, I probably would not want to load the entire thing into memory.  XmlReader will allow you to read (forward-only) the XML file little bits at a time, and insert into the database as you go.

Comment: If all the application is doing is loading the XML, 500MB isn't even big for a 32 bit  process.   Why make this more complicated than it is?

Comment: Thanks. Great comments. Any Open Source Tools/API that might help in XML Parsing ? Such as SAX for .net etc ? What do you guys think about it ? I used SAX Parsing technique for Java environment, but never in .net. This is a Microsoft stack. So if you have any idea/comments on .net Open Source XML Parsing please feel free to share with me. - Thanks.